# What is this game involving moving circular levels and small balls that get moved up and down them?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember a childhood game for many player, with each player receiving multiple small plastic balls. The balls were placed on the game board, a circle with many moving levels, each with indentations for the ball. On each turn, a player could move a level as far as they wanted until a ball fell from the level above. Any idea what game this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description seems to match [Stadium Checkers](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8945/stadium-checkers), or it's [Tournament variant](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/23653/tournament-stadium-checkers).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [Valkuil](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/98943/mb-spellen-dutch-edition-1965) — its Dutch name. The English name is [Stay Alive](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2770/stay-alive).

Comment: No, not quite what I had in mind.

Comment: Ok. It is based on the same principle. "Loosing your marbles".

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are referring to [Abalone](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/526/abalone)

Comment: No, this game had rotating plastic rings with indentations. When the rings were rotated, the balls fell from one ring to the next.

Comment: No need to downvote it, simply not voting it might serve the cause here.