# Wooden circular tower with independently revolving multi-holed layers and wooden balls

Tags: identify-this-game

In the 60s or 70s my parents played a game that looked like a layered circular wooden tower. Each layer could be turned independently, and had holes around its perimeter. The game was played by loading red or black coloured wooden balls onto the top wooden layer. The balls would fall into the holes. You turned one or more of the lower layers to get the holes to line up, thereby getting one or more of the wooden balls to fall out of the lowest wooden layer, which you could count towards points. The game consisted of loading balls into the top layer, turning lower layers so many times, and then the next person would have a go. I don't know what the victory conditions were---maybe first person to accrue so many points. Could have been a Euro game.

There is a similar question here but none of the answers provided match with I remember: [What is this game involving moving circular levels and small balls that get moved up and down them?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33822/what-is-this-game-involving-moving-circular-levels-and-small-balls-that-get-move)

Comment: Do you have any pictures to provide as those can help identify a game.

Answer (score 10):

Might it be Tårnspil aka Tower by Skjøde Skjern?

Marbles are placed into a tower with three wooden tumblers that can be turned in either direction. Players earn points when marbles fall out of the bottom of the tower.

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/22667/tower

[image]

Comment: @Rene That's great! I hope it brings back good memories. When you get a chance, could you click the check box to accept the answer?